# MySQL - where is "Database name" setting?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, phpmyadmin, sql-grant

It's long time I didn't use MySQL.

I have some websites using Wordpress using connection variable like :

```
define ('DB_HOST',  'localhost');
define ('DB_NAME',  'patbrt_cv');
define ('DB_USER',  'patbrt_cv_user');
define ('DB_PASS',  'password');
```

Today I need to import one of my tables (exported from PhpMyAdmin) to my local server (using EasyPHP) for test and to do this I have to use the phpmyadmin configuration file ("config.inc.php")

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

But where is defined the "database name" (the DB_NAME setting) ? How to set it on local database server (EasyPHP) ? I can’t find this setting in "config.inc.php" file (used by phpmyadmin).

I need this setting to import one of my tables from one of my website to EasyPHP using BigDump (successfully installed) to avoid this error I presently get just after database importation attempts

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `patbrt_cv` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
MySQL: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'patbrt_cv'
```

Comment: did you try to manually add `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['dbname'] = 'patbrt_cv';` ? does `user` has permissions to work with `patbrt_cv` database?

Answer (score 0):

If your php client is already logged into MySQL, the query `USE mydatabase;` gets you to the database you want to use.

You can also make the choice of database in your MySQL connection string.

When you log in to MySQL, you use a set of credentials (origin host / usename / password). That credential set must be `GRANT`ed permission to access the database you want to use.   In your example you have zero-length strings for username and password -- as shown here:

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

Your error message says this:

> MySQL: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'patbrt_cv'

This means your php program successfully logged in to your MySQL server with the origin / username / password credential combination of  `localhost / (empty) / (empty)` but that particular credential combination does not have privilege to use the database `patbrt_cv`, or perhaps does not have the privilege to get a list of databases already present on the server.

You may want to try a username of `root` and whatever root password is set up on your local MySQL server. That will give your php program access to the server to do things like issue the command `SHOW DATABASES;` to retrieve a list of databases already present on your server.

EasyPHP is a Windows bundle. That means you can use one of the excellent Windows MySQL clients. Download and install a client like HeidiSQL (https://www.heidisql.com/download.php) and use it to look at the contents of your local MySQL system.   It also has a system for creating user credentials and grantint privileges to them (Tools / User Manager)

Why is this business of credentials so complex, you ask? Because MySQL is designed to be a shared multi-tenant system where different users use different databases without having to know about each others' existence, and certainly without being able to see each others's data. You don't use those multitenant features when you run MySQL on your own machine, but they are still present.